# LDAP JNDI Tomcat - can connect but not login

Tags: tomcat, ldap, context.xml

### Problem

I want to move tomcat-users.xml data (roles, usernames) to LDAP.

I can successfully connect to the LDAP through JNDI, but I cannot set roles in LDAP for users to access Tomcat. 
I'm following this,

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html

and have the LDIF setup as they do, but no success yet.

### Environment:

- Tomcat7
- ApacheDS
- Netbeans

### Source

here is my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/simple-service-webapp">

   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
   debug="99"       
        connectionName="uid=admin,ou=system"
        connectionPassword="MYPASSWORD"
        connectionURL="ldap://localhost:10389"
          userBase="dc=mycompany,dc=com"
          userSearch="(cn={0})" 
   userPassword="userPassword"
   userPattern="uid={0},ou=users,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
      roleBase="ou=groups,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
      roleName="cn"
      roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"    

   />
   </Context>
```

and here is an image of my ldap: 
[ldap config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oMIf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP wrote:

> I worked with the nice folks over at #apache-directory and got a working ldap configuration:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
         connectionURL="ldap://localhost:10389" 
         connectionName="uid=admin,ou=system"
         connectionPassword="ThisIsMyPasswordToConnect"
         userBase="ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com" 
         userSearch="(uid={0})" 
         userRoleName="memberOf" 
         roleBase="ou=groups,dc=mycompany,dc=com" 
         roleName="cn" 
         roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})" />
```

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))